# how to hide current date and time in BIRT report

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I am generating report using BIRT. The problem which i am facing is that date and time is automatically generated at each page in the report. I do not want those field to appear in my report. does any one know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Your question indicates that you are a newbie to BIRT, so I'll explain a bit more:

The field is in the footer in the master page.

You can simply delete it if you don't want it:
Just open the master page tab of the main window, scroll down to the bottom, find the text element containing "new Date()" and delete the element.

When you create a new report, the wizard lets you choose a template.
The so-called "blank report" template isn't actually blank! 
It contains very few predefined elements: Apart from some styles, the only visible element is the current date/time in the footer of the master page.

You could create your own "really blank" report template, if you like.

IMHO the templates are kind of superfluous.
Once you have developed a few reports, it is easier to copy a similar existing report and modify it than to create a new report from scratch.

BTW if you are going to develop more than a handful of reports, you should learn about BIRT's library concept, which is really useful to re-use components in different reports.

Comment: I am not able to find any text element new Date in master page tab. Can you provide a screenshot of the same

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Master Page view of the .rptdesign window and you can remove the date there.[image: refer]